# Design a non-negative monotonically decreasing function $f$ with $f(0)=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am looking for a non-negative monotonically decreasing function $f$ with $f(0)=1$. Currently, I found several function as

1. $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\lambda x}$, where $\lambda$ is tuning parameter
2. $f(x)=\exp{(-\lambda x)}$
3. $f(x)=\max(x)-x$

where $x \ge 0$

Do you think third equation ($\max(x)-x$) also satisfy above requirement? Could you suggest to me several functions which have that properties? Thank all

[image]

Comment: What is the $\max$ function?

Comment: I don't know what function is intended.

Comment: the first function is negative when $x< - \frac 1\lambda$

Comment: Sorry. max mean maximization of x

Comment: $x$ is  given and $x>0$

Comment: Wht is $\max(\pi)$? What is $\max(42)$?

Comment: I see. Some confusing in here. $x$ is given and it store in a vector. max(x) means the maximun value of the vector.

Comment: What does monotonic mean in a vector space (which may not be ordered)?

Comment: Also, $\max(x)-x$ is a scalar minus a vector. That is not defined.

Comment: @AlexS: It means third equation is not correct for above requirement?

Comment: @user2938494 Yeah, probably not.

Comment: So, two first equation are correct. Could you suggest to me another equation?

Comment: $1-2(\arctan x)/\pi$

Comment: Well, your explanation of max doesn't make any sense but if max ever equals x more than once that's not monotonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of such functions. Here are some examples (defined on $[0,\infty)$.) I hope the will give you ideas for lots more.

1. $\dfrac{1}{1+a(\log(1+b\,x))^k}$, $a,b,k>0$.
2. $\dfrac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{k_i}}$, $n\in\mathbb N$, $a_i\ge0$, $a_n>0$, $k_i>0$.
3. $\exp(-a\,x^b)$, $a,b>0$.
4. $\dfrac{1}{1+a\,x+b\sin x}$, $a>0$, $|b|\le a$.
5. Any convex linear combination of the above.
6. Any product of the above.

Comment: It looks similar my above function. Have any different function for that?

Comment: All such functions are going to look "similar". One difference is the rate of convergence to $0$ at $\infty$.